# How can i display portfolio images in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

I've a sortable portfolio in my theme. And i want to display portfolio tags images in it. I find [this](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/) plugin for this. But i couldn't customize it very well.

Because i don't want to display posts' category images, i want to display portfolio's tags images in index. I think it will be clear with this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClgEA.jpg) I want to call this images, which you can see from the screenshot, in the index.

Here are my theme codes:

```
<?php

$query = ff_get_query_for_section();
if( !ff_archive_layout_type_test('portfolio', basename(__FILE__)) ){
    return false;
}

ff_require_portfolio_archive_helper_before();


$numberOfPosts = ( $query->get('number-of-posts') ) ;

?>
            <!-- Filter Section -->
            <section <?php ff_print_section_attributes($query->get('section-options-sortable section-options'), 'small-section'); //class="small-section bg-gray-lighter"?>>
                <div class="container relative">
                    <!-- Works Filter -->
                    <div class="container align-center">
                        <div class="works-filter  mb-0">

                        <a href="#" class="filter active" data-filter="*"><?php $query->printText('trans-all'); ?></a>
<?php
$portfolioTagsArray = array();
$portfolioTagsString = '';
$postCounter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $postCounter++;
            $t = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ff-portfolio-tag' );
            if( !empty($t) ) foreach ($t as $onePortfolioTag) {

                if( !isset($portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ]) ) {
                    $portfolioTagsString .= '<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".tag-'.esc_attr($onePortfolioTag->term_id).'">'.ff_wp_kses( $onePortfolioTag->name ).'</a>';
                }

                $portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ] = $onePortfolioTag;
            }
            if( $numberOfPosts > 0 && $postCounter >= $numberOfPosts ) {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    // Escaped HTML with tags
    echo $portfolioTagsString;

?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Works Filter -->

                </div>
            </section>
            <!--  End Filter Section -->


            <!-- Section -->
            <section <?php ff_print_section_attributes($query->get('section-options'), 'page-section');//class="page-section" id="portfolio"?>>
                <div class="container relative">

                    <!-- Works Grid -->
                    <ul class="works-grid work-grid-3 hover-color clearfix" id="work-grid">

 <?php
 $fwc = ffContainer::getInstance();
 $postMeta = $fwc->getDataStorageFactory()->createDataStorageWPPostMetas();
    rewind_posts();
    $postCounter = 0;
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $postCounter++;
            $currentPostId = $post->ID;

            require dirname(__FILE__).'/portfolio-archive-one-post.php';

            if( $numberOfPosts > 0 && $postCounter >= $numberOfPosts  ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- End Works Grid -->

                    <?php
                    if( $query->get('show-pagination') ) {
                        ff_bigstream_print_pagination();
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- End Section -->
<?php
ff_require_portfolio_archive_helper_after();
```

And i tried to add this codes in this file:

```
   <?php foreach (wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ff-portfolio-tag' ) as $cat) : ?>

<?php z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->term_id, 'ff-portfolio-tag'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But i couldn't be successfull. If you help, i would be grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the question?  You will get more assistance keeping to the standard Q / A format.

Comment: I want to display portfolio tag's images(you can view them via screenshot in my first post) with [this](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/) plugin or another way. But i can not adapt the plugin with theme. Because my php knowledge is not very well.

Comment: For example; the php codes which can be found in plugin's official site are: `<ul>
<?php foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : ?>
<li>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>`

And i want to adapt it with my theme. So i don't want to display category images in my site. I want to display portfolio  tags' images. And i think the necessary codes are in my first post. But i don't know which one should i use and combine with this plugin. @jdm2112

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Try this to get the thumbnails, $size default is **'thumbnail'**:

```
  wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

**Second**

This code not tested with your code. Swap out the (taxonomy) for your tag.

Check out this page for more information about the columns you are building in your category page. [Manage $taxonomy id columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$taxonomy_id_columns)

```
function my_custom_(taxonomy)_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns = array(

        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', // must keep

        'image' => __( 'Image' ),

        'title' => __( 'Isim' ),

        'tanim' => __( 'Tanim' ),

        'yazikisaismi' => __( 'Yazi Kisa Ismi' ),

        'toplam' => __( 'Toplam' )

    );

    return $columns;

}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-(taxonomy)_columns', 'my_custom_(taxonomy)_columns' ) ;
```

Comment: Where should i add this code? In my template file or..?

Comment: Ahh no... This is not at all Template file code, But put it in your custom folder and include it once in the child theme functions.php file. When you become an experienced WP developer, then you can create your own code for a Plugin.